# HTML5 Types in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

Site will exclusively be used on mobile devices. So for fields requiring only numeric input, I want to bring up the numeric keypad. I can successfully do this by using an html input element with the type set to `tel`. I want to add an `asp:RequiredFieldValidator` to this field and based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972961.aspx).

I need to set the input to `runat="server"`. When I do this, I get this error;

> `tel` is not a valid type for an input tag.

If I remove the `runat="server"`, I get

> Unable to find control id `Contract` referenced by the `ControlToValidate` property of `''`

Here is my code:

```html
<input type="tel" runat="server" id="Contract"></input>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Contract" 
                            ValidationGroup="IfOnRent" Text="*" 
                            ErrorMessage="Contract Required">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Am I just out of luck and have to code my own validations?

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you, as a basic courtesy towards others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to leave "type" undeclared in your code "front". You can set this in the code behind (maybe in the `Page_Init` or `Page_Load`):

```
this.Contract.Attributes.Add("type", "tel");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Reliability Update 1 (KB2533523) installed, than `TextBox` accepts new html5 input types (you would need it for `UpdatePanel` to recognize them on postback too).

Or you can just inherit `HtmlInputText` in your own control (any .net version - any input type):

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:Input runat='server' />"), Themeable(true)]
public sealed class Input: HtmlInputText { }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C#

```
Contract.Attributes["type"]="tel"
```

Writing inline types for html inputs may produce **parse error** in .net.  So add the above line of code in your **PageLoad()**

Answer (score -2):

you can use 
Make sure that the submit button has the same validationgroup property value as the requiredfieldvalidator

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question.  The issue is that I cannot use an asp.net validation control with a client side html input.