# Unable to parse HTML5 in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, iis

I am having a problem with a simple ASP.NET form. I have coded it locally and tested it locally by hitting <kbd>F5</kbd>. I have now uploaded it to my server but I am getting parser errors.

> Parser Error Message: 'email' is not a valid type for an input tag.

My code is as follows:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" ID="email" placeholder="your@email.com" runat="server" required />
```

My server is Windows Server 2012 R2 running IIS 8.

- If I run the page using <kbd>F5</kbd> it works perfectly on an address like `http://localhost:55343/` it works .
- If I navigate to `http://localhost/site/form.aspx` I get the parser error.
- If I navigate to `http://example.com/form.aspx` I get the parser error.

I have looked that the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801120/html5-email-input-cannot-assign-id-and-runat-server-asp-net-4) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888110/html5-types-in-asp-net) but they do not appear to be relevant.

What am I missing?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232079/how-can-i-use-html5-email-input-type-with-server-side-net)

Comment: @Yab I referenced that in my question. The procedures mentioned there no longer appear to be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

This parsing error happens when the project is targeting .NET Framework 4 or older.

There's a couple options to fix:

- Change target framework to .NET Framework 4.5 or later.

OR

- Remove `type="email"` from input tag and add in code behind in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load`:

```html
tbEmail.Attributes.Add("type", "email");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I believe that the projects were both 4.5 and that we were missing some DLLs from the build. Thankfully this project was killed off in 2017.